# Hilt dependency injection in multi-module project

Tags: android, kotlin, multi-module, dagger-hilt, android-multi-module

I have two modules in my android app, `app` and `data`. `data` module contains retrofit dependency and `app` module depends on `data` module.

app/build.gradle:

```kotlin
implementation project(':data')

implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

data/build.gradle:

```kotlin
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit_version"
```

In `data` module, I have the following Hilt module:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
internal object DataModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideLoginApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): LoginApiService {
        return retrofit.create(LoginApiService::class.java)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideLoginRepository(loginRepository: LoginRepositoryImpl): LoginRepository {
        return loginRepository
    }

}
```

Here, `LoginApiService` and  `LoginRepositoryImpl` are internal in `data` module and `LoginRepository` is public (in `data` module):

```kotlin
@Singleton
internal class LoginRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val loginApiService: LoginApiService
) : LoginRepository {
    // ...
}
```

Now when I try to build the project, I get the following error:

```kotlin
DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:41: error: package retrofit2 does not exist
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
```

The error goes away if I add retrofit dependency in my `app` module which I don't want to do.

What's happening here and how can I resolve this error without adding `data` module dependencies in `app` module?